# Using Statsmodels for OLS Regression

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

I've been going crazy trying to understand why I kept getting a key error with the following line:

```
X = df['1d ret','5d ret','3d sma','10d sma','10d ema',]
```

Then I realized I was missing another [] around it.  Can anyone explain why I need 2 square brackets for this but not this line?:

```
Y = df['return_sign']
```

What am I missing about the X dataframe?

Thanks so much

Comment: In the first example, you are indexing using a list, so you need the inner brackets. In the second example, you are indexing with a scalar, so you don't need list notation.

Comment: Thanks.  So the inside [] is for the column headings or 'list' and the second is for the df?

Comment: Python uses [] to denote a list. Pandas uses [] for indexing dataframes and series.